# Android Async task getting result back

Tags: android

I am calling Async Task class in my main activity:here is code

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AsyncResponse {

                    @Override
                    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



                        Connection connection=new Connection();
                        connection.execute();



                    }
        Here is my Connection class:
        class  Connection extends AsyncTask<String,String, Void>
        {
            public AsyncResponse delegate=null;
            String result = "";
             InputStream is=null;
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {


                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                /*ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = null;
                  int i=0;

                     String username=params[i].toString();
                     String password=params[i+1].toString();
                     String validation=params[i+2].toString();
                  nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));

               //  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",));*/
                try{
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/connection.php");
                      //  httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                         is = entity.getContent();
                }catch(Exception e){
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                }

                try{
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                        is.close();

                        result=sb.toString();
                }catch(Exception e){
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                }
                return null;
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

             try{


                 JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                 delegate.processFinish(jArray);

               //  labels2.add(password);


               //Returndata(labels2); 

             }

             catch(JSONException e){
                 Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
         }
        }




        }
```

On post execute I am sending Jarray to an interface:and using that interface in my main Activity:
            Here is my interface:

```
public interface AsyncResponse {

            void processFinish(JSONArray jArray);

        }
```

And using it main activity like this:

```
 @Override
        public void processFinish(JSONArray jarray) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                for(int i=0;i<=jarray.length();i++)
                   {
                             JSONObject json_data;
                json_data = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                String  username=json_data.getString("username");
                 String password=json_data.getString("password");
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),username+password,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

                 }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code? Did you get any errors?

Comment: I am getting fatal main exception , Null pointer exception and onpostexecute error

Comment: 02-23 10:02:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(836): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 10:02:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(836): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-23 10:02:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at com.example.seprateconnectiontesting.Connection$task.onPostExecute(Connection.java:77)
02-23 10:02:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at com.example.seprateconnectiontesting.Connection$task.onPostExecute(Connection.java:1)

Comment: 02-23 10:02:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
02-23 10:02:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
02-23 10:02:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
02-23 10:02:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

Comment: 02-23 10:02:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-23 10:02:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-23 10:02:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 10:02:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

Comment: 02-23 10:02:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-23 10:02:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-23 10:02:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 3):

Just a suggestion When your doInBackground method returns String the params in onPostExecute will have that return value of doInBackground. You don't have to declare a seperate String. Have a look below,

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         String someresult = "got from some operations";
         return someresult;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         System.out.println("The resulting string from doInBackground is " + result);
     }
 }
```

Secondly with Connection class you have,

```
public AsyncResponse delegate=null;
```

You haven't initialized the delegate variable, it null!! So you have a Null pointer exception. You can never instantiate an interface in java. You can, however, refer to an object that implements an interface by the type of the interface. Hope this helps.

Edit:

If you have a interface implemented by class B then you can have`AsyncResponse  test = new B();` like below

```
public interface AsyncResponse 
{
}
public class B implements AsyncResponse 
{
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    AsyncResponse  test = new B();
}
```

Now in Android you cannot instantiate an Activity. Instead have a reference to that activity instance. I bet you have a methods there.

Comment: Thank for your support but didn't solve my problem.I have already declared public Asynchronous delegate=null; and result has nothing to do with this code because i am using result as a global variable thats why i am returning null in background and simply using result in onpostexecute

Comment: I didn't really mean to say using string as global and returning null is causing you a problem. It was just a suggestion. But the second explanation has. `delegate.processFinish(jArray);` in your onpostexecute is your problem. Its null as you have declared right? So you have a delegate which is null.

Comment: Yes sir this is the problem i have debugged my code when i am sending data to delegate.processFinish(jArray); it is giving problem.Can you please tell me how i can make object of my interface class

Comment: I guess you haven't read my answers properly. But I'll edit my answer for you now.

Comment: 02-23 11:09:10.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1963): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 11:09:10.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1963): java.lang.StackOverflowError
02-23 11:09:10.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):  at java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference.<init>(FinalizerReference.java:42)
0

Comment: 02-23 11:09:10.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):  at java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference.add(FinalizerReference.java:54)
02-23 11:09:10.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):  at android.os.StrictMode$InstanceTracker.<init>(StrictMode.java:2194)
02-23 11:09:10.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):  at android.os.StrictMode.trackActivity(StrictMode.java:1896)

Comment: 02-23 11:09:10.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):  at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:755)
02-23 11:09:10.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):  at com.example.seprateconnectiontesting.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:27)

Comment: Now, did you instantiate like  `AsyncResponse delegate = new MainActivity()`?

Comment: Yes i have instantiate it like that because my Main Activity is implementing that interface

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25010/discussion-between-jjpa-and-sammar-javed)

Answer (score 0):

I think the code do not declare the interface that is in use.

In the MainActivity class should declare something below.

The connection thread that you have created did not declare any interface.

And hence it will be declared to null value.

```
        public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AsyncResponse {

            Connection connection=new Connection(); // You shud declare on top

                @Override

                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                    connection.delegate=this;

                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


                    connection.execute();



                }
```